# Somewhat special question with additional information on question

Tags: support, specific-question

I just found that question [Why does my C# gzip produce a larger file than Fiddler or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435200/why-does-my-c-sharp-gzip-produce-a-larger-file-than-fiddler-or-php)
on SO and noticed that

[image]

How was this additional information added to the question. My first thought was that it belongs to a bounty, but there was no bounty provided on this question.

Using the search [hasnotice:1 is:q gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasnotice:1%20is:q%20gzip) indicates that the question is somewhat special. As far as i know is that `hasnotice:1` finds questions that are `locked` or offer a `bounty`. But i don´t know why this question is so special (Its a good question with good answers, but it seems not to be locked).

Comment: [Notice added Insufficient explanation by Robert Harvey♦](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11435200/revisions)

Comment: Everything is explained in the duplicate question. So deleting my answer.